# Taking the second derivative of the moment generating function.

Tags: probability, derivatives, moment-generating-functions

I am following along from a proof of the central limit theorem using moment generating function from [this lecture](https://youtu.be/OprNqnHsVIA?si=IChnUTlDz9OBcgyo&t=2189).

At one stage, we are taking derivatives of the moment generating function of an r.v. $X$, $M_X(yt) = E[e^{Xyt}]$ w.r.t $y$.

The first deriative makes sense,

$M_x(yt) = M_x(yt)'t$

by the chain rule.

Now, if we want to take the derivative again, in the lecture by the chain rule again:

$$\left(M_X(yt)'t \right)' = M_X(yt)''t^2$$

This I don't understand, taking the first derivative as a function, $g(M_X(yt))$, then should the second deriative not be (again by the chain rule):

$$g(M_X(yt)t) = g(M_X(yt))' M_X(yt)' tt = M_X(yt)''M_X(yt) t^2$$

Why is this wrong?

[EDIT]

Further to Mikes comment, I thought it would be useful to write it out the problem with full reference of what the derivative is w.r.t

$$
M_X(yt)' = \dfrac{M_X(yt)}{dy} = \dfrac{M_X(yt)}{d(yt)}\dfrac{d(yt)}{dy} = \dfrac{dM_X(yt)}{d(yt)}t
$$

$$
M_X(yt)'' = t \dfrac{d \bigg( \dfrac{dM_X(yt)}{d(yt)}\bigg)}{dy}
$$

This is the step I am having trouble conceptualising. I guess now, we are asking how the change in the function $M_X(yt)$ as $yt$ changes, itself changes as $y$ changes.

In this case, we care how a small change in $y$ changes $yt$ and then, now a small change in $yt$ changes the first derivative of $M_X(yt)$ w.r.t $y$.

$$
M_X(yt)'' = t \dfrac{d \bigg( \dfrac{dM_X(yt)}{d(yt)}\bigg)}{d(yt)} \dfrac{d(yt)}{dy} = M_X(yt)''t^2
$$

If this conceptualisation is correct, does anyone have further reading or way of building intuitive / proof of it?

Comment: You cannot think of the first derivative as a function, $g(\cdot)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are way over-thinkning this. You are correct that
$$
\frac{d}{dy}[M_X(yt)]=M_X'(yt)\cdot t\tag1
$$
Now, take the derivative with respect to $y$, again.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dy^2} M_X(yt)
  &= \frac{d}{dy}\left[\frac{d}{dy} M_X(yt)\right]
\\&=\frac{d}{dy}\left[ M_X'(yt)\cdot t\right]\tag{substitute (1)}
\\&= t\cdot \frac{d}{dy}[M_X'(yt)] \tag{$t$ is constant w/r.t. $y$}
\\&= t\cdot \frac{d}{dy}[ty] \cdot M_X''(yt)\tag{chain rule}
\\&= t^2 M_X''(yt)
\end{align}
$$
Let me be crystal clear about the chain rule step. The chain rule says that
$$
\frac{d}{dy} f(g(y))=g'(y)\cdot f'(g(y))
$$
I am applying this with $f(y)=M_X'(y)$ and $g(y)=yt$. By defintion of the second derivative, $$f'(y)=[M_X'(y)]'=M_X''(y).$$

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful